# An example of a continuous function on $\mathbb R^2$ with two critical points, both of them minima

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Knowing you can not use the minimum bound, there exists a function $f ( x , y )$
continuous in $\mathbb R ^ 2$ that has exactly two critical points which
are (both) the minimum? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of a function with two maxima and no saddle points. I saw it on a mathematics professor's home page once—I think, someone who was even a prominent user here—and I simply cannot remember who they were. I hope someone will let me know in the comments so I can credit them.

Take a function with two maxima and a saddle point between them, say
$$\begin{align}
f(u,v)&=g(u,v-1)+g(u,v+1)\\
\text{where}\quad g(u,v)&=e^{-u^2-v^2},
\end{align}$$
and transform the domain to send the saddle point to infinity:
$$\begin{align}
u&=\operatorname{softmax}(x,-y^2)=\log(e^x+e^{-y^2}),\\
v&=y.
\end{align}$$
Then $f$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ has two maxima and no saddle points.

[image]

---

*Update:* I just came across [a note](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/260S12/notes/several-var-intuition.pdf) by Jerry Kazdan which gives a recipe for "a smooth function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ having exactly $M$ local maxima, $s$ saddle points, and $m$ local minima, all non-degenerate, and no other critical points":

> To construct an example, take a function $g$ with infinitely many non-degenerate maxima,
>   saddles, and minima, for instance $g(x,y):=\sin\pi x\sin\pi y$. Pick the required number of maxima, saddles, and minima, Let $\Gamma$ be a smooth curve with no self-intersections that passes through these critical points and no others. Then let $\Omega$ be a tubular neighborhood of $\Gamma$ that contains no additional critical points. There is a diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\Omega$. The desired example is $f:=g\circ\phi$.